# Barcode scanner for a react application

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, barcode-scanner

I'm developing a reactjs application, there i need to read bar code values and scanned value should be popped up in a specific text box, any idea or at least i need to know if this is how feasible to do ..

I need to use a  physical USB Barcode scanner.

Comment: How do you intend to scan the barcodes? You will upload an image? Or you have attached barcode scanner for the client using the app?

Comment: I need to use a physical USB Barcode scanner.

Comment: Physical barcode scanners act as a keyboard, so if you set focus to the text field where you want the code to be placed by default, once you scan the code, it will appear in the text field, the scanner can be configured to add an (Enter) or (Tab) at the end, so that you can handle this to process the scanned value.

Comment: then can i use this package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-barcode-reader ? will that be the solution?, since you said barcode scanners act as a keybord, then will i be able to set focus to a text field.

Comment: Yes, you can use this package.

Comment: If you are going to use a hardware barcode scanner, there is no special solution required for the app. You just need to use `<input type="text">`. When running your barcode scanner, it will automatically input the barcode results into the text field.

Answer (score 4):

This component helps to read the barcode from device into react application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-barcode-reader

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import BarcodeReader from 'react-barcode-reader'


    class Test extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          result: 'No result',
        }

        this.handleScan = this.handleScan.bind(this)
      }
      handleScan(data){
        this.setState({
          result: data,
        })
      }
      handleError(err){
        console.error(err)
      }
      render(){

        return(
          <div>
            <BarcodeReader
              onError={this.handleError}
              onScan={this.handleScan}
              />
            <p>{this.state.result}</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't do anything, the Barcode component doesn't open the camera.

Comment: I used this for bar code reader for bar codes which are printed in papers

Comment: this code is nor working

Answer (score 1):

Doing a google search I found this 
https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/ it generates barcodes

This will read barcodes 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/barcode-js

Answer (score 0):

if you need bar code reading this library will work

https://codesandbox.io/s/tgo42
[image]

Comment: Does this libary support barcode scanner hand device